# Why does the elbow score increase as K range widens with yellowbrick KElbowVisualizer?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to understand why as the K Range widens in yellowbrick KElbowVisualizer, the elbow score increases. It seems very arbitrary based on how wide your K Range is, and I'm wondering what the reason for this increase is.

How does one choose an appropriate range to begin with?

I don't have enough points to post images, but here is a link to a table showing the Elbow Value increasing as the K Range widens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKs6z.png

Here is the code that produced this:

acs_scaled_pca is census data with 70 principal components that's been scaled using StandardScaler

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer

# Create KMeans instance
km = KMeans()

# How does the Elbow Value change as the K Range increases?
val_dict = {2: [10,15,30,40,60,80,100]}

# Loop through different K ranges
for key, vals in val_dict.items():
    for val in vals:
        visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(km, k=(key,val))
        visualizer.fit(acs_scaled_pca)
        visualizer.show()
```

Comment: How did you calculate the score per run? As I understand the documentation of Yellowbrick, the score is computed per value of _k_. Or does your table mean that this is the optimal score for some _k_ during that run? In that case it is expected, when adding more clusters the fit becomes better - the idea of the Elbow method is to check where the curve starts to bend, not what the highest score is.

Comment: @Marijn Sorry, it's not so much a score as it is the optimal value of K given a range of Ks. Here is what the output looks like https://i.imgur.com/NUByA7Z.png 
So in general it's better to run a wider range so that the fit becomes better?

Comment: No, it's not about the best fit (which is k=n by definition), it's about the least amount of clusters with still a good fit. This is the 'elbow', the part of the graph where the increase of the fit starts slowing down.

Comment: @Marijn Okay, yes that's fair. Is there a good rule of thumb for choosing a range of K values? The wider the range, the higher the elbow value, but it seems so arbitrary. It's especially hard with this dataset since there is a very gradual drop off. Thanks for answering my questions!

Comment: Choosing _k_ depends on domain knowledge and what you actually want to do with the clusters, if it's census data then probably you are looking for less than 10 clusters in order to get some meaningful demographic groups. Then you take the range a bit around that, maybe 1-20. This is all rather off-topic for Stack Overflow though, it would be better to ask a question on [Data Science.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [AI.SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) or [Statistics.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead.